# Running e4 RCP application on GTK2

Tags: eclipse, gtk, rcp, e4

This question is a continuation of my [attempts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39456363/e4-rcp-application-and-linux-gtk3-compatibilities?noredirect=1#comment66235131_39456363) to make e4 rcp application run on recent Linux distros.

I am starting my RCP application with the following option:

```
--launcher.GTK_version 
2
```

The **first** launch fails and it took me a while to figure out the reason - missing xmi file:

```
.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi
```

How do I make the workbench load without this file for the first time?
There are absolutely no traces on where and why it fails to load.

The `workbench.xmi` is produced when application gets closed for the first time. And I don't get a chance of the first time. I manually produce this file by running the application without `--launcher.GTK_version 2` switch. Then having this file in place makes the application run fine with GTK2. And this is what I am trying to achieve.

Any help on how to overcome this chicken-or-egg problem will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As you say that file is created the first time you exit your RCP, it should not need to exist on your first run. What is happening to make you think the missing file is the problem?

Comment: Pure experiment. I place the file there - it works. I remove file from there - it crashes, or freezes. The last thing I see in the progress splash screen is that it loads css something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem, it was an internal issue in my app where I was doing some illegal things in `WorkbenchWindowAdvisor.preWindowOpen()`. Once I moved the 'criminal' code to `WorkbenchWindowAdvisor.postWindowOpen()`, the problem is gone. I still have no idea why workbench.xmi file had such a side effect, but it's not relevant anymore.

Just a reminder, we were trying to force the e4 RCP application fall back into GTK2 because as of now the SWT and GTK3 is so full of bugs and it's hard to understand who is who in all this. Frankly, I think such versions like neon shouldn't be released to public use.

What helped me to resolve the issue was using [remote debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385558/how-can-i-remote-debug-my-rcp-application), it was one of those cases when you have no idea what is going on inside your eclipse application.

Comment: Keep in mind that Eclipse 4 is an effort of volunteering developers of which not all are being paid for what they do for the Eclipse community. The solution should be to invest time and resources to improve SWT on GTK3, not banning Eclipse from the public :-)